# How to do cross database join using spring jdbc

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a table A in db1 and table B in db2. I wanted to do a join between db1.A and db2.B and get the result.

The sql query for this in Microsoft SQL server would be something like this

```
    select a.name from db1.A a
     join db2..B b on
    a.id = b.id
```

Now, I am not sure how would I perform the above query using springJdbcTemple. I have setup the datasource and sping jdbc template for db1.A as templateA and templateB respectively.

Do I need a global transaction manager like XA to perform this query even though its just a simple join? 
I am using Spring 3.1.X version.

**Note:**
I have setup the datasource and have simpleJdbcTemple for the datasource with me, but if I run this query using simpleJdbcTemplate I get the bad sql grammer exception stating that table b is not recognised which makes sense as the simpleJdbcTemplate is accesing db1 and not db2.

Comment: You will need to define `dataSource` as bean & access it in this file by `Autowiring` it. you need `ResultSetExtractor` and `RowMapper` and class into which you want to load data.

Comment: I have setup the datasource and have simpleJdbcTemple for the datasource with me, but if I run this query using simpleJdbcTemplate I get the bad sql grammer exception stating that table b is not recognised which makes sense as the simpleJdbcTemplate is accesing db1 and not db2.